# Locking nodes when deleting from threaded linked list

Tags: linked-list, thread-safety, locking, pthreads, mutex

I'm new to pthreads and I need to safely delete nodes from a linked list that is shared by all threads. I am not completely understanding when to lock and unlock a node. This is what I have so far for removing a node that is the head. I lock the head before it is accessed (it is accessed in the while condition) but when do I unlock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting a node, you can't just lock the node itself: because you're changing the pointer *to* that node, which is stored outside of the node, you need to protect that pointer from concurrent access.

In other words, you can't use `head->lock` to protect `head`, because `lock` is *inside* the node, and the pointer `head` itself is not.  For example, you could have a lock declared alongside `head` called `head_lock`.

This also affects how your code that adds to and looks up the list works - that code needs to lock `head_lock` while it accesses the `head` pointer, too.

Whether or not you should just rely on the single `head_lock` to protect the entire list, or *also* have individual per-node locks depends on how you use the list nodes and the amount of contention there is for access to the list.